# Pulling down the Drop Down Notification Sheet Resets/Reloads the Swift WKWebView Content back to the top

Tags: html, ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

[Demo Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE32i.gif)
How do i stop this reset and let the screen stay as it is even if i pull
down the notifications screen?

Below code is what i use to display the html data thats coming from an API.i just pass
the URL to this struct and this struct will take care of displaying the data.

```
struct URLView : UIViewRepresentable
{
    
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView { return WKWebView()
        
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) { uiView.load(request)
    
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading request each time SwiftUI updates view. This is not a good solution, coz there are a lot of cases that causes updates (size, orientation changes, etc.)
Move your request loading to makeUIView

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.load(request)
    return webView
}
```

Comment: i've tried that, it's still behaving the same. Any idea where else i could be going wrong?

Comment: I've checked on my device, even your code working well. Seems like something wrong outside this view. Maybe you can share more details?